# How do I close DVDs when burning on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, dvd, burning, dvd-burning

When I burn DVDs using Explorer on Windows 7, there is no option of closing the DVD. This results in some MBs of free space after the DVD has been written (multisession). How do I close the DVD on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through few web pages it seems that it ain't possible with windows.
I mean windows just closes a session and keeps to open for further sessions.
There doesn't seem to be any option to finalize the disc.

why don't you use some free disc burning tools such as [infrarecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/)?

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  It is possible to write a single session disk in Windows 7 you just have to tell Windows 7 this is what you want.  Of course the simple solution is also to use a media type that can only be written to once.

Comment: If you are so sure about it, why don't you write a detailed answer.
I would be happy to know how because I need to use nero for that sole purpose.

PS: The discs that can be written once(CD-R/DVD-R) are capable of multisession!